# using jQuery and style dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with this code:
if you click the "appened text" twice you will get 2 divs one with content of "hello2"
and one with "hello3", but for some resone when you click on them they open the same block.
insted of having each of them opening his own block.(I want to keep it dynamically created.) thanks for the help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
var k=1;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
function appendText()
{
  k=k+1;
  var css = '#flip'+k+' { padding:5px; text-align:center; background-color:#ffff00;   border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;}',
  head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
  style = document.createElement('style');
  style.type = 'text/css';
  if (style.styleSheet){
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
  } else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  }

  head.appendChild(style);

  var css = '#panel'+k+'{padding:50px;display:none;text-align:center; background-   color:#'+k+''+k+''+k+''+k+''+k+''+k+'; border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;}',
  head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
  style = document.createElement('style');
  style.type = 'text/css';
  if (style.styleSheet){
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
  } else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  }
  head.appendChild(style);

  var flip2 = document.createElement("div");
  flip2.innerHTML = "Hello"+k;
  flip2.id = ("flip"+k);

  var panel2= document.createElement("div");
  panel2.innerHTML = "Hello"+k;
  panel2.id = ("panel"+k);

  document.body.appendChild(flip2);
  document.body.appendChild(panel2);

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(("#flip"+k)).click(function(){
      $(("#panel"+k)).slideToggle("slow");
    });
  });
}
</script>

<style type="text/css"> 
#panel,#flip
{
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#e5eecc;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel
{
padding:50px;
display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button onclick="appendText()">Append text</button>


<div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to make a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Whats with the variable `k`?

Comment: @Nate it's there to make the code not work :-)

Comment: Why mixing jQuery and plain js when dealing with DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your variable `k` is **global**.  When it changes, then your event handlers all see the same value (first 2, then 3, then 4, etc).

Set up your event handlers like this:

```
(function(kk) {
  $(("#flip"+kk)).click(function(){
    $(("#panel"+kk)).slideToggle("slow");
  });
})(k);
```

There's no reason to use a "ready" handler at all inside the function that adds the elements.

Comment: You understood what `k` is!